# MATLAB - Using urlwrite with https Site Not Working in OS X

Tags: macos, matlab, pdf, https, file-writing

I am currently attempting to use the `urlwrite` function in MATLAB to download a PDF from the internet. I have been using this method successfully for a while now, but I ran into a new problem last night. The site from which I download the pdfs changed from http to https, and now I get an error in MATLAB when I run my usual code. I am trying to run the following:

`urlwrite('https://statsdmz.nba.com/pdfs/20160407/20160407_TORATL.pdf',
'/Users/dwm8/Desktop/test.pdf');`

but get this error when I do:

`Error using urlreadwrite (line 98)
Error downloading URL. Your network connection may be down or your proxy
settings improperly configured.`

`Error in urlwrite (line 38)
[f,status] = urlreadwrite(mfilename,catchErrors,url,filename,varargin{:});`

I did some digging here, and it looks like it may have something to do with Java packages, with which I am not at all familiar. I am running MATLAB 2015a on Mac OSX. Does anyone have a fix for this issue? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried going to the site in a browser?

Comment: interesting, so urlwrite is not supporting https connections? can you try putting http:// and let it re-direct you and see what happens?

Comment: @excaza Yes I have no problem accessing the pdf in a browser. (I'm using Chrome). As mentioned, the url is https://statsdmz.nba.com/pdfs/20160407/20160407_TORATL.pdf

Comment: @GameOfThrows I am able to enter http://statsdmz.nba.com/pdfs/20160407/20160407_TORATL.pdf in my browser with http instead of https, which redirects me to the desired https page, but when I run `urlwrite('http://statsdmz.nba.com/pdfs/20160407/20160407_TORATL.pdf',
'/Users/dwm8/Desktop/test.pdf');` in MATLAB, I get no error message. However, it saves an empty pdf called `test.pdf` which, when I try to open it, gives the error message `The file “test.pdf” could not be opened because it is empty.`